# Create a valid URL from a String

Tags: objective-c

Is there any API or good function to format strings like
"www.example.com" or just "example.com" to valid urlstrings like
"http://www.example.com"?

```
+ (NSString*)complete:(NSString *)urlString
{
    NSArray * urlParts = [urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    if(urlParts.count==3)
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.%@.%@",[urlParts objectAtIndex:1],[urlParts objectAtIndex:2]];
    else if(urlParts.count==2)
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.%@.%@",[urlParts objectAtIndex:0],[urlParts objectAtIndex:1]];
    return nil;
}
```

this is what current solution looks like, but this doesn't look very good and solid to me.

Comment: What you have currently is really bad. As it doesn't take into account many possibilities. You may want to look at using regex to check if you have a valid URL instead of componentsSeparatedByString. Currently your code would ig nore a string like http://www.thebestsiteintheworld.com/index.html which would be bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily with `NSDataDetector`:

```
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:NULL];
NSString *URLString = @"www.example.com";
NSTextCheckingResult *result = [detector firstMatchInString:URLString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, URLString.length)];
if (result) {
    NSURL *URL = [result URL];
    NSLog(@"%@", URL); // http://www.example.com
}
```

You should not assume that `www` is a valid subdomain for any given domain btw.

If you need the result as a string, you can use the `absoluteString` method of `NSURL`, it's typically better to use `NSURL` instead of `NSString` for URLs though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the kind of solution i was looking for